# Using auto-incremented index value of another column as default value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite3 but this is more of a generic SQL question. I need to duplicate the primary index value (integer type, auto-incremented) to another column of the same table on insert.

**It could be done by a trigger but I would rather do it by default value if possible.** Is that possible? How would the expression look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLite, it is not possible to get the autoincremented value until after the row has been inserted.

You have to update the value manually:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO MyTable ...")
c.execute("UPDATE MyTable SET AnotherColumn = ?1 WHERE rowid = ?1",
          [c.lastrowid])
```

or use a trigger.